# Trying to understand how list gets modified while iteratively reversing a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, reverse, pointer-to-member, iteration

I have the following code which iteratively reverses a linked list.

```
 struct list {  
   int elem;
   list *next;
 };
  /* .... */

void ReverseListIterative(list **listref) 
{

    list *currNode = *listref;
    list *prevNode = NULL;
    list *nextNode = NULL;

    while(currNode) {
        *listref = currNode;
        nextNode = currNode->next;
        currNode->next = prevNode;      
        prevNode = currNode;
        currNode = nextNode;
    }   
}
```

In the code, currNode,prevNode and nextNode are all pointers local to ReverseListIterative(). How come the original list still gets modified (gets reversed, to be more precise) ? Should'nt we be using

```
 list **currNode;
 list **prevNode;
 list **nextNode;
```

so that actual addresses of the list nodes get modified ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No we shouldn't.

You don't want to change the addresses of the nodes in memory (which means changing their location), but rather how they are pointing to each other, i.e: to which node does each node point, and this is done by changing the `next` which happens in these lines:

```
nextNode = currNode->next;
currNode->next = prevNode;
```

If we use `list **currNode`, I should be saying:

```
*nextNode = currNode->next;
*currNode->next = prevNode;
```

But what did that benefit me?

We're only changing how the nodes are connected to each other, and the connections are `next` in each node, so only the values of them should be changed.

Hope that's clarifying enough :)

Comment: I figured out the same thing once I asked the question. We can change information within a node, which includes what address the pointer variable next contains.